# JavaScript idiom: !something && function()

Tags: javascript

I have been looking at the source code of [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/index.html) and I see a lot of stuff like `!variable && function()` (e.g.: `!svg.bottom && (svg.bottom = this);` )

What does that exactly do? Does it check first and execute only if not true?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Correct. This is (ab)using short-circuit evaluation. A boolean expression is only executed as far as is needed to determine the result. In your example, if `svg.bottom` is non-null, then `!svg.bottom` is `false`, and the result of the `&&` is `false`, so execution of the right hand side does not happen. It's basically equivalent to `if(!svg.bottom)svg.bottom = this;`

Comment: Using of such short-circuit evaluation is good or bad? Default settings in eslint say that it is bad, why?

Answer (score 8):

When you have boolean operations, the compiler start check one by one each condition, and stops when its sure for the results - for example if you ask

```
if(a && b && c)
{    
}
```

if **a** is false, then the full **boolean question is false**, and compiler **did not** need to check b and c. **This compiler feature is used to short the writing code for some cases.**

This is (for me) a bad practice that writing code like.

```
!variable && function()
```

instead of

```
if(!variable) function();
```

try to minimize the size of the javascript ?

Difficult to debug, and difficult to find what actually dose in many cases.

See this similar code.

```
unsigned uCycleCheckBox(unisgned uCur)
{
  return ((uCur <= 1) ? (uCur?0:1) : (uCur==4)?2:(uCur+1));
}
```

is the same think... hard to understand, hard to debug, hard to change and fix in case of problems.

For the comments on that, I suggest to read the books, Writing Solid Code, and Debugging the development process.

Writing solid code is more important than everything else.

Comment: What is hard to understand?! ;)

Comment: And only the existing of the question, must make you think again, yes is hard to fast understand what the code dose, its also dificult to debug, and imaging that the code is not only for the one that write it.

Answer (score 6):

It uses short-circuiting rules to perform the second part of the expression (which actually includes assignment) only if the first part (`!svg.bottom`) is not false. That is if svg.bottom is `null` - set it to `this`.

Comment: `!svg.bottom && (svg.bottom = this);` is quite weird though... It would be simpler to just do `svg.bottom = svg.bottom || this`.

Comment: @EFraim, not only if `svg.bottom` is `null`, also if it's `undefined`, `0`, `NaN` an empty string, and of course `false`.

Comment: Yeah, its like abbreviated 'if' statement, although it would be clearer to use 
if (!svg.bottom) {
    svg.bottom = this;
}

Comment: @Vivin put the second expression between parenthesis, it should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

There are two handy ways of using logical operators in JS, because they are not merely boolean operators.

With `&&`, you can say "if this expression is true, it's safe to evaluate the next expression". The most common usage is to check if a property is non-null before digging further inside it:

```
var result = myObj.person && myObj.person.firstName;
```

If `myObj.person` is undefined, the value of `result` will be undefined also.

With `||`, you can say "take the value of this expression if it's truthy (not null or undefined in this context), otherwise use a default":

```
var result = person.firstName || "Sid";
```

Combining the two:

```
var result = (myObj.person && myObj.person.firstName) || "Sid";
```

A quick way to say "get the `firstName` from the `person` property of `myObj`, or use "Sid" if the `person` has no `firstName` or `myObj` has no `person`".

The example you refer to is a bit strange though. Doing a side-effecting operation inside an expression is a bit ugly. It's usually easier to keep track of what you're program is doing if you clearly separate "read-only" expressions from variable-mutating statements.

**UPDATE:**

Two more recent features improve on this. First, `?.`

```
var result = (myObj.person?.firstName) || "Sid";
```

And second, `??`, which may be closer to the desired behaviour:

```
var result = (myObj.person?.firstName) ?? "Sid";
```

This means that `"Sid"` will only be the `result` if the right-side expression is `null` or `undefined`, where as `||` is much looser: `"Sid"` will be the `result` if the value is falsy, which includes `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `NaN` and (importantly here) the empty string.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has many strange casting conventions. The `!` operator will cast to a boolean. If the test fails, the part after `&&` will not be run.

Some examples:
`!undefined` is true
`!false` is true
`!0` is true 
`!1` is false
`!"hello"` is false

Comment: Though I believe `!""` is `true`.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker it is