# Angular: How to reference the result of a function in the new control flow @if with an logical AND (&&)

Tags: angular, control-flow

With the old control flow I could reference the result of a function in this way.

```
<span *ngIf="column.getValue && column.getValue(item) as value">{{value}}</span>
```

But when I use the new control flow (@if) it throws the error `Parser Error: Unexpected token 'as'`

```
@if (column.getValue && column.getValue(item) as value) {
<span>{{value}}</span>
}
```

I've already tried the following, but to no avail

```
@if (column.getValue && (column.getValue(item) as value))
```

It seems to me that it should be possible, but I can't find how.

FYI: `column.getValue` is an optional function, that's why I'm checking if it exists before executing it.

Comment: It doesn't work because they didn't implement it. Related github [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/52103)

Comment: @Eldar That issue is about `@else if`. It should work for `@if`.

Comment: @Eldar Thanks for the heads up. As I'm looking into my code, it actually fails on the `@else if`, but I've changed the code in my question for clarity and changed the `@else if` to `if` and that should actually work indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control flow syntax also allows to alias condition result, you need to use `;`:

```js
@if (column.getValue && column.getValue(item); as value)
```

You unnecessarily put another curly brackets. This is an alias for the whole condition, which works as follows:

- if `column.getValue` is `null`, return `false`
- if `column.getValue` is not `null` return result of `column.getValue(item)`

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586768/javascript-idiom-something-function)

FYI: if `getValue` is optional, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) here:

```js
@if (column.getValue?.(item); as value)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've changed my code for the question and in doing so removed the problem in itself. I have an issue with referencing the result in an `@else if` instead of an `@if`, but apparently they don't support that

Comment: Indeed, `@else if` isn't, and probably won't in the future, supported for aliases. I suggest using computed signal instead of function evaluation in the template.